# How to user json store in Java map

Tags: karate

I am newbie and I have store my json requst and response to be asserted in a java hashmap. How can I read it in feature file and use it? I am reading reques and response from kafka and storing in a hasmap to be used in karate.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the section titled [Java API](https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api) in the documentation. All the best.